# Page Not found 404 when i try to create a new comment to Post object?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to let users create comment from listview on the social app am working on currently but am having a hard time working out the pattern. I keep getting the Error 404 when i try to load the listview. Here is Formlist view which my Post list view inherit from.

```
class FormListView(FormMixin, ListView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
            comment = request.GET.get('comment', False)
            post_obj = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
            session_obj = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            create_comment = Comment.objects.create(
                                            post=post_obj,
                                            user=session_obj, 
                                            comment=comment)
            create_comment.save()
            
        # From ProcessFormMixin
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        self.form = self.get_form(form_class)
        # From BaseListView
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()
        if not allow_empty and len(self.object_list) == 0:
            raise Http404(_(u"Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.")
                          % {'class_name': self.__class__.__name__})
        context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list, form=self.form)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == "POST":
            description = request.POST['description']
            pic = request.FILES.get('pic', False)
            #tag = request.FILES['tag']
            user_obj = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            post_data = Post(username=user_obj,pic=pic,description=description,)
            post_data.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Posted Successfully')
            return redirect('feed:feed')
        
            
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

For one strange thing am able to create New Post from the PostListview but, Comment has been a challenge for me, for the past two weeks now and i have look on here but can't seem to find a solution that fits mine.

```
class PostListView(FormListView):
    model = Post
    form_class = NewPostForm
    form_class = NewCommentForm
```

This is my comment model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My Form.py

```
class NewCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment']
```

Here is my URL for PostListView.

```
path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='feed'),
```

Comment: you will have to show your `urls.py` and the URL that is giving you 404.

Comment: I Just share my url @Abhyudai

Comment: what is the name of the app that this resides in?

Comment: The app name is feed! @Loukik